# Match everything between start string and a possible termination string

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say we want to match everything between `start` and `end` but adding `end` is optional. If we know end is going to exist its easy

```
var re = /start(.*?)end/
```

How would we create a similar regexp with an optional end? I naively tried unsuccessfully

```
var re = /start(.*?)(end)?/
```

Some assertions to make my case clear:

```
re.exec("startA string end")[1] === "A string ";
re.exec("startA string ")[1] === "A string ";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try imposing the presence of `end` or end of string:

```
/start(.*?)(end|$)/
```

The problem with `/start(.*?)(end)?/` is that `(.*?)` won't match anything because it's lazy (as few times as possible) and, since `end` is optional, it won't force it to include more characters.